Linear regression solution comparison
I tried to solve this exercise several times now using different methods but I am not really sure if my solution is correct.
Please help me and tell me what your solution to this problem is, so I can compare and maybe ask more questions about your solution:
Consider the rent of these five flats:
Space in sqm: 15, 20, 10, 25, 35
Rent in USD: 220, 310, 180, 340, 650
Which is the correct equation for a regression function of the form $y(x) = cx^2$ for the rent y according to the space x using least squares?
My solution for c is $\frac{6495}{15715}$.
Thank you for your help!

Applying the LS method to the requested model $y=cx^2$ the ansatz is to minimise
$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-cx_i^2)^2\ $, what is
$$c^2\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^4+\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}^2-2c\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 y_{i}\tag{1}$$
Differentiate this with respect to c
$$2\left(c\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^4-\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 y_{i}\right)$$
Set it to $0$ and solve for $c$
$$c=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^4}$$
Note: the $2^{nd}$ derivative of $(1)$ is independent of $c$ and positive, thus this $c$ is a minimum.
With your figures the result is $\ \displaystyle c=\frac{1.200.250}{2.111.875}$

Thank you so much for the quick response and the explanation! I understood what I did wrong now and will try to solve more exercises like this.
